# how to send mail from Web-mail in Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, cpanel, webmail

I have successfully send email from my application using Gmail account.

Now I want to send email using Web-mail account from my application.

After changing inside `.env` and `config/mail.php` files,s I can't send mail and got error

> local.ERROR: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "info@sencare.com.bd" using 2 possible authenticators

**`.env` file**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=sencare.com.bd
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=info@sencare.com.bd
MAIL_PASSWORD=&&Pass@2018&& //my webmail password, not application specific password like gmail
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**`.config/mail.php` file**

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),


'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'sencare.com.bd'),


'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),


'from' => [
    'address' => 'info@sencare.com.bd', 
    'name' => 'Bacekend System',
],

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

Comment: The obvious question - are you sure the username/password are correct? Can you configure a normal mail client (Thunderbird, Outlook, etc) with those details? If you have metacharacters in your password, try putting it in quotes.  Also - I hope that is not your real password that you have shown here.